# Construct object's square bracket notation from array values

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array with unknown number of values. For example: `['one', 'two', 'three']`.

How can I construct a square bracket notation for an object from it? Basically, I need to create this: `var result = myObject['one']['two']['three']`.

They key here is to understand that there can be any number of values in the array and I just need to go n-levels deep into the object using these values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
var o = myObject;

for (var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
    o = o[yourArray[i]];
}
```

Or with `Array.reduce`, which looks nicer but won't work in older browsers:

```
var o = {
    'one': {
        'two': {
            'three': 'four'
        }
    }
};

['one', 'two', 'three'].reduce(function(object, key) {
    return object[key];
}, o);
```

Comment: yeah, noob me misunderstood the question and embarrassed myself by making fun on others ... x_x

Comment: Thanks! Decided to use `reduce()` because I need this on node.js only :)

Answer (score 1):

Short and precise with help of [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce):

```
var o = { 'one': { 'two': { 'three': 'five' } } };
["one","two","three"].reduce(function(prev,cur){return prev[cur]},o);
```

reduce works from IE9 on.

Comment: That's the reverse of what the OP wants…

Comment: @Bergi just recognized that... ;) fixed it.